# oracle sql 2 columns in one column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My db looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+
|FN   |LN   |
+-----+-----+
|FN1  |LN1  |
|FN2  |LN2  |
|FN3  |LN3  |
+-----+-----+
```

Edit: 
I tried:

```
SELECT FN || ' - ' || LN Name FROM TBL;
```

Output:

```
+-----------+
|Name       |
+-----------+
|FN1 - LN1  |
|FN2 - LN2  |
|FN3 - LN3  |
+-----------+
```

But what I want is to join them in the same column but is separated by new line like this:

```
+-----+
|Name |
+-----+
|FN1  |
|LN1  |
|FN2  |    
|LN2  |
|FN3  |
|LN3  |
+-----+
```

Note: FN and LN is in the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will place a newline character into the output - which is perhaps all you intended by this *"Note: FN and LN is in the same row"*

```
select
     ( fn ||chr(10) || ln ) as name
from tbl
```

If more rows are in fact needed though using a cross join may be used to form more rows, and a case expression to selectively output from the source columns:

```
select
     case when n.n = 1 then tbl.fn else tbl.ln end as name
from tbl
cross join (select 1 n from dual union all select 2 from dual) n
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `union all`:

```
select fn as name
from t
union all
select ln
from t;
```

If you care about the ordering:

```
select name
from (select fn as name, rownum as seqnum, 1 as ord
      from t
      union all
      select ln, rownum as seqnum, 2 as ord
      from t
     ) t
order by seqnum, ord;
```

Note that with no `order by` in the subqueries, you are not guaranteed that the results will be in the same order for the two subqueries.  Ideally, you need a column that specifies the ordering of the rows in the table.

Comment: Sir @Gordon Linoff, I edited my question to be clearer. I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

You may use `LISTAGG` for concatenating rows and  `CHR(10)` for newlines.

```
SELECT listagg(fn 
               ||chr(10) 
               ||ln, chr(10)) 
         within GROUP ( ORDER BY fn, ln) AS Name 
FROM   tbl;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5098521226e0bfe1110db59050178f9c)